# How to compare 2 NativeImage instances in Electron

Tags: javascript, performance, electron, javascript-objects

I'm reading images from the clipboard in a setInterval loop and I want to check if the user has clicked a new screenshot since the last run.

Currently I'm using the toPNG() method and comparing the buffers to the previous one. Is this the most efficient method? Can I directly compare two NativeImage objects or should I use some other methods like toJPEG() or toDataURL(). Which method has the least overhead?

My current solution:

```js
let newImg = clipboard.readImage();
let data = newImg.toPNG();
if (!Buffer.compare(data, prevImg)) return;
prevImg = data;
```

Any way that I can avoid using toPNG?

Answer (score 0):

Better to compare with a function other than `toPNG`, since that is by far the slowest of the various `NativeImage -> Buffer|string` conversion functions:

```
toPNG --- 144ms
toDataURL --- 0ms
toBitmap --- 4ms
toJPEG(0) --- 13ms
toJPEG(100) --- 25ms
```

Test code (on 1920x1080 image):

```
const measureNext = (name: string, func: ()=>any)=>{
    const startTime = Date.now();
    func();
    console.log(`${name} --- ${Date.now() - startTime}ms`);
};
measureNext("toPNG", ()=>image.toPNG());
measureNext("toDataURL", ()=>image.toDataURL());
measureNext("toBitmap", ()=>image.toBitmap());
measureNext("toJPEG(0)", ()=>image.toJPEG(0));
measureNext("toJPEG(100)", ()=>image.toJPEG(100));
```

So I use `toDataURL` for mere content-comparisons, eg: `img1.toDataURL() == img2.toDataURL()`

Note that for `Buffer`'s, an alternative to `Buffer.compare(buf1, buf2) == 0` is: `buf1.equals(buf2)`